# How do I allow for multiple dtoverlays? (SX400 DAC and Tontec screen work alone, but not in conjunction)

Tags: audio, touchscreen

I'm working on a particular musical project that requires both of these devices to be working, yet if both dtoverlay=mz61581 (the screen) and dtoverlay=iqaudio-dac-overlay (DAC) are uncommented in /boot/config.txt, only the screen works. If I comment out the screens dtoverlay, sound works again. I apologize, I'm completely new to dtoverlays and research into the subject hasn't been much help. Any ideas on how I can have both of these work at the same time?

I read the "conflicting dtoverlays" question on this site, but it unfortunately didn't provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a single dtoverlay parameter with comma delimited values, i.e.

```
dtoverlay=mz61581,iqaudio-dac-overlay
```